# no "--prune" option

Tags: git, github

I would like to delete all the **remote branches** which are not exist in **local repository**.

I tried command:

```
git push --prune origin
```

But my git complains with the following error:

```
error: unknown option `prune'
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --repo <repository>   repository
    --all                 push all refs
    --mirror              mirror all refs
    --delete              delete refs
    --tags                push tags (can't be used with --all or --mirror)
    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    --porcelain           machine-readable output
    -f, --force           force updates
    --thin                use thin pack
    --receive-pack <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    --exec <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    -u, --set-upstream    set upstream for git pull/status
    --progress            force progress reporting
```

Why my git does not have `--prune` option??

Answer (score 3):

The `--prune` option was introduced to git in version 1.7.10. You probably simply have an older version installed.

For reference, compare the docs for [1.7.9](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-push.html) with those for [1.7.10](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.10/git-push.html).

Comment: Then, which option should I use to achieve my goal?

Comment: Well, you could simply update your git. If that is not feasible, you probably would have to loop over your local branches yourself and check if there is a remote counterpart. Should be possible with a bit of shell scripting...

Comment: @john123 Another option is to remove the branches one by one. `git push origin :branchname`. Notice the colon before the branch name.